# Center and bottom div into parent div

Tags: html, css

Im trying to center and put fixed in the bottom a div that is inside another div, i'm trying with this piece of bits but not success, can someone help me accomplish this?

```
#clockPosition {
    margin: auto auto 0 auto;
    width: 30%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.parent-column {
    margin: 1%;
}

<div class="parent-column">
     <>
    <div id="clockPositon">Content here</div>
</div>
```

Here is an image how i want to the final result:

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrs_snow/w3nu7ghv/)** with the bootstrap thing as well if you need it.

```
 <div class="parent-column col-md-5">
    <div id="clockPosition">Content here</div>
</div>

#clockPosition {
    width: 30%;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    bottom: 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
.parent-column {
    margin: 1%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 80%;
    position:relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your version is failing primarily because positioning top, bottom, etc requires a div to be absolutely positioned, which you don't define.  By making the inside absolute (and setting the bottom) and the parent relative (as in the absolute is relative to the parent) then you'll be good to go.

To position relative to a parent div:
HTML:

```
<div class="outside">
   <div class="inside">Center and bottom">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outside {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
.inside {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -40%;
    height: 20px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

To simply fix a div to the bottom of the page, regardless of parent elements:

```
.foot-nav{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Finally, to do a sticky footer that's part of the page, but always on the bottom unless the page is longer than one screen (my preferred method for fixed footers with adaptive sizing)

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: the parent class have too a col-md-5 bootstrap class and the width is 100% i want the div stays fixed at the bottom of the page

Comment: I wish you would have been more clear in the beginning, if you just want it fixed to the bottom of the page, just do position fixed.  I'll update with that.